Detect device of where an Iframe is embedded
I understand that in javascript the best way to detect where a device is opened is using the size of the screen. The problem is that the project that I am working on will be embedded using an iframe and it's size will be fix, and there might be a scenario where the size will pass as mobile size even though it is embedded in a web. Is there a known package for react to detect a device aside from the screen size, I tried detect-device package but it stills detect a web view the moment the view is shrink.
I tried using detect-device package and screen size solution
